# Negative selector on sortable's cancel property jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm adding to a third party control (tabbed control) the functionality to reorder its tabs by drag and drop. Only the selected tab should be allowed to be moved. For this I'm using the sortable function with the cancel property in jquery ui.

The control has a div that contains the tabs (also are divs), but also the div tab's contains more divs:

```
<div class="TabControl-Container"> 
   <div class="ui-state-default TabControl-Tab_Selected">Tab 1
       <div>tab container</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-state-default">Tab 2
       <div>tab container</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-state-default">Tab 3
       <div>tab container</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-state-default">Tab 4
       <div>tab container</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

To restrict the movement only the tab is selected, I'm doing a negative selector in the cancel property:

```
$(function () {
    var dummy = $(".TabControl-Container");

    $(dummy).sortable({
        cancel: 'div :not(.TabControl-Tab_Selected)'
    });
});
```

It is disabling the tabs except the "Tab 1" (thats OK), but the problem is that the divs contained inside the Tab 1 are also disabled. I need that the divs (or any tag like image) inside the Tab 1 can be dragged or the hole tab cannot be moved.

You can see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/WD2Rw/24/

Comment: so you need to move the images from one tab to another, even if the tab itself is disabled?

Comment: No, if the tab is disabled should be not moved. The problem is because the top most div of the tab can not be selected because doesn´t have any text, so the only way to move it is from the inner divs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `not child of` selector will be supported in CSS4, currently, this is not the case.

This could be a workaround on modern browsers which support CSS property `pointer-events`:

{ but nested elements won't be responding on mouse events }

http://jsfiddle.net/WD2Rw/27/

```
$(function () {
    var dummy = $(".TabControl-Container"),
        nestedElem = $(".TabControl-Tab_Selected *");
    nestedElem.css({pointerEvents:'none'});

    $(dummy).sortable({
        cancel: 'div :not(.TabControl-Tab_Selected)'
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested your sample and it works, but in my project doesn't. May be the problem are the versions of the jquery libs I'm using (jquery 1.4.2 and jquery-ui 1.8.2) and is not possible to update them :( . I saw the pointer events in the styles of the div's, but I'm not sure if it will work when the selected tab change (the whole tab control is not recreated), because there is a need to execute again this function for the new tab and remove the styles for the old one. Any way thanks, I will do it in another way.